# prettier vscode "r is not a function"

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

Been using prettier in vscode for a while, but it recently stopped working and I'm not sure if it's a bug on their end or a misconfiguration of mine.

```
["INFO" - 02:54:03] Loaded module 'prettier@1.19.1' from '/Users/paulrberg/.nvm/versions/node/v10.17.0/lib/node_modules/prettier'
["INFO" - 02:54:03] Formatting using 'prettier-eslint'
["ERROR" - 02:54:03] Error formatting document.
r is not a function
TypeError: r is not a function
    at /Users/paulrberg/.vscode/extensions/esbenp.prettier-vscode-3.13.0/dist/extension.js:1:352891
    at t.default.safeExecution (/Users/paulrberg/.vscode/extensions/esbenp.prettier-vscode-3.13.0/dist/extension.js:1:353582)
    at t.default.<anonymous> (/Users/paulrberg/.vscode/extensions/esbenp.prettier-vscode-3.13.0/dist/extension.js:1:352865)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at s (/Users/paulrberg/.vscode/extensions/esbenp.prettier-vscode-3.13.0/dist/extension.js:1:347571)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There was a bug in version 3.13.0. Upgrade to the latest and the issue will go away.

Comment: How to install a specific version of a vscode extension?

Comment: you can just go to Extention menu > Prettier - Code formatter >  Click on Setting (gear icon) > Install Another Version  > Choose version 3.11.0

Comment: Looks like v9.5.0 also has this same bug again. I downgraded to v9.4.0 and that resolved it. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error yesterday. I'm using eslint with prettier in a Gatsby project and was able to resolve the issue with

```
npm install --save-dev prettier-eslint
```

Then reloaded VS Code window and forced a manual Format Document from CMD Palette and the errors went away.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this was a bug with the v3.12.0 version of the extension. Either downgrade to a lower version like v3.11.0 or upgrade to v3.13.0 and up.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (my Prettier was on 3.13.0). To solve the problem I downgraded to 3.12.0.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation/release notes for 3.13.0? Maybe they have made breaking changes on this function, but made other important improvements. Downgrading should be a last resort.